# Are There Infinitely Many Primes of a Certain Form?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

**Definition.** Let $S_n = 3^n - 2^n$ for every positive integer $n$.

**Question.** Are there infinitely many primes $p$ such that $S_p$ is (not) prime?

**Some Facts.**
(a) For any positive integer $n$ such that $S_n$ is prime, $n$ must clearly be    prime.
(b) There are primes $p$ for which $S_p$ is (not) prime.

---

**Generalization of the Original Question**

**Lemma.**  Let $x$, $y$, $n$ be integers such that $x > y > 0$
and $n > 1$.  If $x^n - y^n$ is prime, then both $n$ is prime
and $x - y = 1$.

**Conjecture.**  Let $x$ be a positive integer.  Then there are
infinitely many primes $p$ such that $(x+1)^p - x^p$ is (not)
prime.

An interesting question would be which conjectures hold for
$\frac{x^n - y^n}{x - y}$.

Comment: I would like to believe that this is as hard or harder than the question "Are there infinitely many Mersenne primes?", which is an unsolved problem.

Comment: There's a few relevant references at http://oeis.org/A057468. The answer doesn't seem to be known.